# Использование YouCompleteMe для подсветки синтаксиса

Tags: vim

Пользуюсь таким плагином как `YCM` и задумался вот о чем: этот плагин позволяет автодополнять методы класса, а что насчет их подсветки в коде? Тобишь, можно ли это плагин использовать для подсветки синтаксиса в `vim`. `Vim` не может подсвечивать такие данные, так как использует для подсветки регулярные выражения и синтаксис-файлы. Ему все равно просто ли это функция, метод, переменная или тип - если это набор символов не встречается в синтаксис-файле и не соответствует регулярному выражению, то `vim`-y не объяснить что нужно подсветить. Но! `YCM` как раз таки, знает, что является типом, методом или просто функцией. В мануале я, к сожалению, ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

Comment: https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/291#issuecomment-264686718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порылся в нете и нашел [вот этот плагин](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/411) - оказывается не только я об этом задумался). В конце предлагают замечательный плагин, который делает как раз то, что требуется: [color_coded](https://github.com/jeaye/color_coded). Я только начал им пользоваться, но могу сказать вещь хорошая. Он прост и делает как раз то что нужно.

UPD: `color_coded`, конечно, хороший плагин, но из-за своей конструкции имеет ряд неустранимых недостатков (медленная работа, огромный расход памяти, краш `vim` и т.д.). Это побудило меня написать свой [клиент](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/vim-hl-client)-[серверный](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/hl-server) плагин, который лишен этих недостатков (опять таки - в силу конструкции).